# logstash file reading interval not working

Tags: file, logstash, intervals

I am pretty new to Logstash and Elasticsearch.
I have a Problem that I am not able to configure out. 
My configuration is for testing is a 2 EL nodes running on OS X + Kibana and Logstash. All with the actual stable releases.

I am reading with logstash a log with following informations:

```
64.12.89.186 {"register":"07-015", "tag":["Server1", "Proxy", "Web", "picture"], "comment":"texttext"}
149.174.107.97 {"register":"07-015", "tag":["Server1", "Proxy", "Web", "picture"], "comment":"texttext"}
149.174.110.102 {"register":"07-015", "tag":["Server1", "Proxy", "Web", "picture"], "comment":"texttext"}
```

and write them in EL.
Configurationfile from logstash is this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["/scenario_02/data/ipinfo4_log"]
        stat_interval => 1
        discover_interval => 5
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{IP:ip} %{GREEDYDATA:data}" }
    }
    json {
        source => "data"
    }
}
filter {
    geoip {
        source => "ip"
        target => "geoip"
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

So far so good. The new informations will be added at the end of the log file.

Now to my Problem: The file  are read only when I start logstash.
When in the log file get new informations during logstash is running, no new documents will be written to EL.
When I stop logstash and start it again. The new informations from the log file will be added.

Did I understand something wrong that the informations from the log file will not added or checked automatically in intervals ? Or I have to restart always logstash to read the file again?

Thanks a lot for your help.
Paris

Comment: Try not to specfic stat_interval and  discover_interval

Comment: Is working process from logstash different, when it is running ?

Comment: @Ben: I tried it, it make no diffence. Next I will try to run it as a server under linux.

Comment: I meen service not server.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
start_position => "end" after 'path => ...' . It can help, but end is a default for start_position. BTW, if you are using lumberjack? then files always will be checked for a new info by default.

Comment: I've tried your tip. It makes no differents. No at the moment i'm not using lumberjack (logstash_forwarder) but now i'm looking for it. I reconfigured my logstash for it and startet the forwarder, but it is showing some error's that the certifcate is not for localhost... so I look for this error now.

Comment: My advise is to use forwarder, if you want I can help you with configuring it - I had some troubles with certificates too, but solved it. You can show me your conf files and logstash-forwarder.err log.

Comment: I followed your advice and configured the forwarder, it is working fine. I have only one Problem, maybe you can help. The log file will be overtime it is changed completely transferred from forwarder to logstash, but I want only transfer the new last line in the file. I didn't find any option where I confirm it. I don't know if it will configured in forwarder (files) or logstash (lumberjack). Did you have a idea where this will be done and how. Thx for Help.

Comment: AGAIN MY LAST COMMENT I followed your advice and configured the forwarder, it is working fine. I have only one Problem, maybe you can help. The logfile is always transferring completely from forwarder to logstash, but I want only transfer the new last line in the file. I didn't find any option where I configure it. I don't know where it will configured, in forwarder (files) or logstash (lumberjack)? Did you have a idea where this will be done and how. Thx for Help.

Comment: I think you can use "dead time" parameter. Default for this parameter is 24 hours. If file is older than "dead time" logstash would not harvest it. And you can configure smth like logback or log4j or smth else to split log files and gzip old files. And in logstash config you can set not specific file, but file mask or exclude *.gz files. This is how I harvest files. Hope this will help.